# Error when downloading expo with yarn - is there a problem with yarn or expo?

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface, expo

I am trying to setup my environment to start working on react-native but yarn doesn't seem to properly install expo-cli.

I tried installing with npm, but apparently npm is buggy today (i'm am in a class and all who work on IOS had problems installing with npm). now that we are using yarn, it has worked for everyone but me.

```
error /Users/nicolaspage/toto/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/nicolaspage/toto/node_modules/sharp
Output:
info sharp Using cached /Users/nicolaspage/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.4-darwin-x64.tar.gz
ERR! sharp Please delete /Users/nicolaspage/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.4-darwin-x64.tar.gz as it is not a valid tarball
ERR! sharp zlib: unexpected end of file
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/page/install for required dependencies
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@11.10.1 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/nicolaspage/toto/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/nicolaspage/.node-gyp/11.10.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/nicolaspage/.node-gyp/11.10.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/nicolaspage/.node-gyp/11.10.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/nicolaspage/toto/node_modules/sharp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
../src/common.cc:25:10: fatal error: 'vips/vips8' file not found
#include <vips/vips8>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/nicolaspage/toto/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v11.10.1
```

Comment: `ERR! sharp Please delete /Users/nicolaspage/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.4-darwin-x64.tar.gz as it is not a valid tarball` – have you done this?

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure I should follow the prompt!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this answer on medium and it worked for me... the error is ususally caused by libvips8.7.4 from the github repo

https://medium.com/@zameermfm/handling-libvip-sharp-errors-in-react-native-expo-installation-8eb592b6314b